# Error when using Typescript MongoDb Typings (Cannot find namespace)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, typescript-typings

i am trying to use mongodb typings which i installed via

```
npm install @types/mongodb -D
```

now i want to use the types in a function like that

```
export default async function insertOne(collection:any, data:any):Promise<InsertOneWriteOpResult> {
  let db = await state.db
  let col = await db.collection(collection)
  let result = await col.insertOne(data)
  return result
}
```

i am specifically interested in the Type of InsertOneWriteOpResult.
but i am getting the typescript compiler error:

```
src/utils/mongodb/collection/insert-one.ts|5 col 17 error| Cannot find namespace 'InsertOneWriteOpResult'.
```

i referenced the typings file in my typings.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="./../node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts" />
```

in this file i can see, that the interface is exported:

```
export interface InsertOneWriteOpResult {
    insertedCount: number;
    ops: Array<any>;
    insertedId: ObjectID;
    connection: any;
    result: { ok: number, n: number }
}
```

So my question is, which namespace do i have to use to let typescript check against InsertOptionsWriteOpResult?

Answer (score 1):

Do not write `<reference path="./../node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts" />`.

Instead write it like this

```
import {InsertOneWriteOpResult} from 'mongodb';

export default async function insertOne(collection: {}, data: {}): Promise<InsertOneWriteOpResult> { 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: @divramod  glad to help :)